# Android Alphabet Scroller

Tags: java, android, listview, scroll, textview

Hey everyone i'm a beginner at android and i'm searching on a way to implements an alphabet index scroller on android , the thing is in my activity i have no listview it's a linear layout with TextViews on it i want to have something like this on the right side of my activity :

A
B
C
D
E
F to Z

And then when i click on the letters it leads me to first letter of the textview

While searching for a solution on the net all i found was related to listview , but i'm not using it .
I only wish for the alphabet scroll bar to point at the first letter of textview

Is there any way to do that ? if so please a hint or a help? Thanks

Comment: You could use a scrollview and populate it with buttons

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[android]+alphabet+listview+header

Comment: @user3427079 exactly i'm using a scroll view and having some buttons and textviews on it , but do you mean even to make the letter as buttons? and on click on the letter it leads to first letter of the textview?

Comment: I see the others have provided a built-in solution but you could add an onClick to the textviews to make them clickable, as long as your activity implements View.OnClickListener or you add a listener in code. Might be useful to know for other times.

Comment: @Arash thanks but i'm not using a listview

Comment: @user3427079 thank you for all the concern but i don't need to make the on click on the textviews the issue is i want the alphabet indexer when i click on A to highlight all textviews that begins with A and lead me there

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AlphabetIndexer.html

I guess this is what you're looking for

Comment: yes this is it but i can't find a way to use it with TextView , i'm not using list view

Comment: Well, depending on what you're really doing on these TextViews inside your LinearLayout, but maybe you could think of changing it to a ListView, so that everything will be built-in : clicking on a letter on the AlphabetIndexer will scroll directly to the right position.

And of course, you can have a ListView with only one TextView in each row (which will do the same as what you have already)